# Custom NSCursor is lost after changing to another window

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield, nscursor

I have a basic Cocoa app with a custom `NSTextField` that emulates a hyperlink.

I use the following code to set the custom cursor in the text field implementation:

```
- (void) resetCursorRects {
    [self addCursorRect: self.bounds cursor: [NSCursor pointingHandCursor]];
}
```

I also overwrote `mouseUp:` and perform an action when the label is clicked on. In my case I'm opening a URL via `NSWorkspace`.

The problem: when the browser opens the "pointing hand" cursor is reset to the normal arrow cursor (since the top most window is now Safari). However, when I return to my app and move the cursor above my custom hyperlink label the cursor does not change to the "pointing hand".

Only after I resize the window (and the cursor rects are reset) does the cursor work again.

I tried invalidating the cursor rect in the `mouseUp:` call, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please add a line of reset before adding cursor rect although it is not recommended on direct call by the document.
Or you may ask the window to do it.

```
[self resetCursorRects];
...
[fatherWindow invalidateCursorRectsForView:self];
...
[self addCursorRect:[self bounds] cursor:[NSCursor pointingHandCursor]];
```

The follow code is used on one of our apps and it works very well:

```
- (void) resetCursorRects
{
    [super resetCursorRects];
    [self addCursorRect: [self bounds] cursor: [NSCursor     openHandCursor]];
}
```